# "Future" step-mom "to be"?

Tags: meaning

I came across the bold sentence from an American TV show, Weird loners, S1E1. In the case of my question, why the dialogue is using **future + to be**, not either of them? Thanks.

According to [google dictionary](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASUT_enMY619MY619&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#es_th=1&q=to%20be%20meaning) ,

```
"to be" means of the future.
Example : "my bride-to-be"
```

Beside, I also came across another example, lawyer-to-be from an English advanced speaker.

Here are the dialogues:

> Stosh: So, Howard, the boys (Howard's sons) must be pretty excited about their ***future
>   step-mom to be***, huh? Uh It's a bit of a work in progress at the
>   moment.
>
> Howard: Milton has some - Pretty violent tantrums. But I'm sure he's gonna be fine once Caryn (Howard's fiancée) moves in, and he sees what a beautiful person she is.

Comment: Probably because it's unrehearsed dialog, and not from a polished script. People make gaffes like that sometimes when they are speaking off-the-cuff. You're right, though: the situation calls for one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @J.R. Hi, I'm not sure whether I need to post a new question or it will be another duplicate question. I just saw another title that "No one wants to hire a 40-year-old **has been**. It occurred to me that it might have same meaning of **to be**,  yet I think it is present prefect tense. Thanks.

Comment: Ask a new question. ELL could use a question about _40-year-old has been_. I don't think it's a duplicate.